# Zuul Reverse Proxy Language Understanding

Tags: reverse-proxy, spring-cloud, netflix, netflix-zuul

I am playing around with Zuul but there seems to be something fundamental I don't understand.

Per the documentation (http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html), The following Zuul configuration should cause all http calls to "/myusers" to be forwarded to the "users" service.

```
zuul:
  routes:
      users: /myusers/**
```

I have a similar scenario but it simply doesn't work. My configuration is:

```
zuul:
   route:
       stores: /california/**
```

The service Id is "stores" and it has a URL called "/hello". When I hit:

```
 http://localhost:8765/california/hello,
```

I get the Spring Boot 404 error message. However, things work very well if I replace california with stores, resulting in the following configuration:

```
zuul:
   route:
       stores: /stores/**
```

In this case, if I call

```
 http://localhost:8765/stores/hello,
```

Things work just fine. So, it looks as if the prefix of the URL has to match the ID of the service. Is that the expected behavior? What am I missing?

I am using the Zuul 1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.
On a aisde note, I did notice that the discovery client is now built in into Zuul. Is there a way to disable it if I don't want to run Eureka?

Comment: what does `/routes` show?  If you don't use discovery, zuul wouldn't work unless you add a fully qualified url to forward to.

Comment: Where is your YAML file? Are you sure it is being used at runtime (your symptoms are consistent with an automatic route added through discovery, and not reading the config file)?

Comment: /routes shows: {"/stores/**":"stores"}; inspite of the fact that in my application.yml, I have: stores: /california/**.

Comment: My YAML file is under src/main/resources. I have no config server. For each run, I delete the target folders manually, then run project clean in eclipse, and then run eureka, stores, and after 3 mins, I then run Zuul.It seems pretty much as IF the route configuration application.yml is ignored. Though I know that the application.yml is being used since if I chance the port the new port is taken into consideration.

Answer (score 5):

Oh my goodness, it should of course be

```
zuul:
   routes:
```

instead of

```
zuul:
   route:
```

Comment: Yup, I just fixed that in [spring-cloud-samples/zuul-server application.yml](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/zuul-server/issues/2)